# Difference rounding 10.075 in Excel (10.08) and VB.net (10.07)

Tags: excel, vb.net, rounding

I am working on an export to Excel feature on my DataGridView, and when I started checking the values I noticed that one of them - 10.075 - displays differently to what I see on my DataGridView.

It seems that in VB.net when I have `Math.Round(10.075, 2)` it rounds to 0.07 and when I have `Round(10.075,2)` in Excel it rounds to 0.08.

I have tried using `Math.Round(10.075, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` and `Math.Round(10.075, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven)` in my VB.net solution, but it doesn't seem to affect this scenario at all.

Also, if I do not apply any rounding in the VB application on this field, and instead use DataGridView Cell Style Format of `C2` it will round the visible value to 0.08 just like in Excel, but then when I use my export feature I export this field as 10.075...

How can I make it so the rounding in VB rounds the same way as Excel?

EDIT: Sorry, initially I had 0.075 as the value in question, but that actually correctly rounded to 0.08... the actual value I have in my application that struggles to round is 10.075, again apologies.

Comment: `Math.Round(0.075, 2)` return 0.08 for me, both in .NET 4.5 and .NET 6.0.

Comment: > when I use my export feature [...] That is the code part you need to add to your post. It's either an error there or you're dealing with a formatting/display issue where the actual correct value of 0.75 is formatted/displayed differently.

Comment: @HelO'Ween That is what is described in the question. When the actual correct value is 0.075, it appears as such in the CSV export. There is no error here.

Comment: I apologise to you both, I did not put the actual value I had in my app on here as I thought using 0.075 instead of 10.075 wouldn't matter... The value that Math.Round(10.075,2) produces is 10.07 for me in VB and 10.08 in Excel.

Comment: @HelO'Ween On the Exporting part - I have 2 exports where one is plain text export, and that exports the values as I see them in my DGV and the second is Export with formulas. As I couldn't figure out a different way to do this. I am actually writing the Excel formulas for each row in DGV programmatically. Having to re-do my equations in Excel formula, I stumbled on this issue where one cell provides 10.07 in my DGV and 10.08 when worked out via Excel formula.

Comment: It matters a great deal because of floating-point. `(0.075).ToString("G17")` vs. `(10.075).ToString("G17")` should illustrate the problem, as do the [notes on the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.math.round#system-math-round(system-double-system-int32)): to round to a particular number of digits the function first multiplies, and `(0.075 * 100).ToString("G17")` and `(10.075 * 100).ToString("G17")` give results that subtly affect midpoint rounding here.